# Prevent write operations on FILESTREAM?

Tags: c#, sql-server, filestream

Running `SQL Server 2012` with `FILESTREAM` enabled. Logged on as a user with read-only rights (`db_datareader`) I successfully run the following code. The `filePath` and `transactionContext` are obtained as described in [storing files in sql server 2008 using the filestream option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463343/storing-files-in-sql-server-2008-using-the-filestream-option).

```
using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    // filePath and transactionContext are obtained as described here:
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463343/storing-files-in-sql-server-2008-using-the-filestream-option

    using (var stream = new SqlFileStream(filePath, transactionContext, FileAccess.Write, FileOptions.SequentialScan, 0))
    {
        var b = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("OVERWRITE");
        stream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
    }
}
```

I want to use `SqlFileStream` for performance reasons, but I don't want my `db_datareader` users to be able to **modify** files! *Adding* files is possible via a stored procedure, which is ok. But from that point, files are considered read-only.

### How can I make FILESTREAM data read-only?

I.e. I want to disallow opening the files with write access!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SqlFileStream` uses normal `FileStream` under the hood, so basically, you are out of the SQL security context. You're using NTFS file permissions.

Easiest solution would be to use *Windows Authentication for SQL server* and to put same Windows account in db_datareader group in SQL, and to give it read-only permision on UNC share.

Answer (score 0):

write wrapper and not realize method `Write()`

Comment: That's not how you handle a security issue like this.